# Electric Potential relative to a point?

Tags: electric-fields, potential

so the question is:

A particle (charge = +2.0 mC) moving in a region where only electric forces act on it has a kinetic energy of 5.0 J at point A. The particle subsequently passes through point B which has an electric potential of +1.5 kV relative to point A. Determine the kinetic energy of the particle as it moves through point B.

my attempt:

[image]

HOWEVER, the answer key claims that KE supposedly decreases to 2 Joules instead of increasing to 8. I don't understand it since the charge and the electric field are both positive! where did i mess up?

Comment: Kinetic energy decreases as potential energy increases

Comment: Yes I wrote that; but the charge is moving to a lower potential energy NOT  a higher one

Comment: +1.5Kv relative to point A so potential at B is greater than A

Comment: electric potential is =  kq/r

Comment: b is farther from a so the electric potential is lower

Comment: But why are using it when the potential difference between the points is already given in the question

Comment: That's what's confusing me; they say electric potential, but the answer key is treating it as if it was a potential difference?

Comment: Yea,that's the general idea here.Remember that conservative forces always try to decrease enrgy like fr eg when you take  mass down by height h,gravitational energy becomes negative and when you take it up ,it increases because in the first case you are moving from lower potential (potential at initial point) to higher potential (potential at Final point up) and vice versa in the second case.Here the similar is happening.You have been given B is at positive potential than A by 1.5 kJ so you are supposedly moving from lower potential to higher potential which will increase your potential energy

Comment: hmm, so their wording meant potential difference not electric potential. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yea so when you take it from A to B then the increase in potential enrgy will be equal to decrease in kinetic energy between the points

Comment: No it's still talking about electric potential energy. The problem says only electric forces are acting on it. The potential difference is the difference in electric potential.

Comment: @AaronStevens  And that potential difference will cause change in potential; energy

Comment: The potential is increasing as we go towards B from A. Vb>Va and Va-Vb<0. You can see that the potential difference is negative between a and b. It takes energy for the particle to reach point B.

Comment: First the math:

Given the electric potential V(a)
at a point a in space and the potential V(b) at another point b, the electric potential energy of a charge moving from point a to point b will change by
U(b)−U(a)=q[V(b)−V(a)]

Comment: It is given that potential difference between B and A is 1.5kV.Check the term relative to the question

Comment: @harambe I was responding to OP's comment, not yours. Sorry.